# Dynamic created input field value in jquery php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am trying to get value from dynamic created input field But its not display nothing in page controller.

jQuery code to append dynamic the input

```js
  var tableRow='<tr>';
        tableRow+='<th><input type="text" class="form-control" name="ar[]" placeholder="Nom Articel" id="ar-'+i+'"></th>';
         tableRow+='<th><input type="text" class="form-control" name="des[]" id="des-'+i+'" placeholder="Description"></th>';
       
        $('#' + tableID + ' tbody').append(tableRow);
```

In the controller I try more then codes but nothing to display

I try to do that:

```html
    $in=$this->input->post("des");
        
if (is_array($in)) {
    foreach ($in as $in => $k) {
      echo "Owner Name is : " . $k . "<br/>";
    }
  } else {
    echo "Owner is not array";
  }
```

The array exist but empty not value of $k

And I try that

```
var_dump($this->input->post('des'));
```

the same nothing display

Comment: where is `Qnt` field??

Comment: `print_r($this->input->post("des"));`

Comment: yes he filed is correct but not display anything

Comment: the problem not in the name of filed the problem nothigng display

Comment: i mean is `print_r()` giving any result??

Comment: this result 
Array ( [0] => )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same variables in loop??, it might have overwritten the value posted from form

```
foreach ($in as $in => $k) {
                 ^
  echo "Owner Name is : " . $k . "<br/>";
}
```

Try changing it to

```
foreach ($in as $in1 => $k) {     
  echo "Owner Name is : " . $k . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: this is the result 
Owner Name is :  

nothing

Comment: Are you filling the values in view??

Comment: Check if its working after keeping in correct place,,,

Comment: you dont have enough reputation to vote.. but you can accept the answer.

Comment: [check this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)